# If Api key was not required, why need an external Javascript script for Google maps?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-api

Few times ago, Google Maps API didn't require an api key.

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

In this case, what was **the purpose of making an http request** to get the script?
Why isn't there an internal script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This allows Google to update the JavaScript as necessary.  It's also likely that the script on Google's servers will already be cached by other pages using maps.

Comment: In this case, what isn't it the case with every other scripts, like jquery?
It would kill the need of tool like Bower for instance, if all Javascript files were external.

Comment: @Mik378 Most folks include jQuery from the CDN as well, for the reason of having already cached scripts.  Tools like Bower are very useful for when you have a lot of scripts to bind together that are less commonly used.  Plus, most libraries aren't available on CDNs unless you put them there.  Tools like Bower also give you the ability to use specific versions of something.  Fortunately, the jQuery CDN URLs include version, so you can be reasonably sure you're getting the right version you need anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Even when you didn't use the key there are limits(e.g. for map-loads).

By requesting the script from a google-server google will be able to count the map-loads(project-based when you use a key or domain-based when you did not use a key)

Comment: What is the mechanism ensuring that Google Map Javascript is not simply internaly copied and thus could exceed the limit ?

Comment: They send 2 requests(to `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/AuthenticationService.Authenticate` and `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/QuotaService.RecordEvent`   ). When these requests don't return the desired result, the API will stop working.

Comment: Excellent, thanks ;)